# REGEXP_REPLACE - remove commas from string ONLY if enclosed in ()'s

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, character

I find an example at oracle forum site :

Input string : `a, b, c (x, y, z), a, (xx, yy, zz), x,`

```
WITH t AS (SELECT 'a, b, c (x, y, z), a, (xx, yy, zz), x,' col1 
         FROM dual)
SELECT t.col1
 , REGEXP_REPLACE(t.col1, '(\(.*?\))|,', '\1') new_col
FROM t
```

Output : `a b c (x, y, z) a (xx, yy, zz) x`

But i want to make opposite of that. Just remove this character `,` from inside `()` and remain outside.

Output : `a, b, c (x y z), a, (xx yy zz), x,`

Comment: how many `,` do you expect between the `()` ?

Comment: REGEXP_REPLACE in Oracle uses the flavor POSIX ERE which has no look around feature. This information is taken from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)

Comment: To add to @bw_üezi's comment - I've confirmed lookarounds aren't supported in Oracle using `REGEXP_REPLACE`. *Mandatory comment*: it doesn't look like data that should be raw in the database - specially if you're going to query it. Are you sure you cannot normalize it? (I know you probably can't at this point...)

Answer (score 3):

This will work for a constant length of arguments with in the brackets.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(t.col1, '(\(.*?),(.*?),(.*?\))', '\1\2\3') new_col
```

update inspired by @Kobi's comment: 
this regular expression removes the 1st, optional 2nd and optional 3rd `,` between `()`
it can be extended up to 9 (I've a [book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596005122/preview) stating \1 ... \500 should be possible but only \1 ... \9 worked)

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(t.col1, '\(([^,]*),([^,]*),?([^,]*),?([^,]*)\)', '(\1\2\3\4)') new_col
```

Comment: You can use something like `\(([^,]*?),([^,)]*?),?([^,)]*?)\)`, `(\1\2\3)` to support 2 or 3 elements, and can easily expand it to a reasonable maximum number of elements. Finding a general regex is tricky in this case...

Comment: how many , do you expect between the () ? infinite :)) therefore, this regular expression must be more general

Comment: @hamdi you can extend this regex shown here to run with 4 elements between brackets to support up to 9 elements. To deal with infinite number of elements SQL may not be the right tool. A more general regular expression can be achieved by 'look around' feature which is NOT supported by Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

A little modified version of the regular expression you used:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, '((\)|^).*?(\(|$))|,', '\1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if REGEXP_REPLACE supports negative look aheads and look behinds, but if it does this would work: `,(?<!\)[^\(]*)(?![^\)]*\()`

I tested with C#:

```
string s = "a, b, c (x, y, z), a, (xx, yy, zz), x,";

Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, @",(?<!\)[^\(]*)(?![^\)]*\()", ""));
```

Comment: REGEXP_REPLACE in Oracle uses the flavor POSIX ERE which has no look around feature. This information is taken from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)