# REGEXP_REPLACE - remove new line \n from string ONLY if is enclosed in ()'s

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to use REGEXP_REPLACE to replace all new line (\n) from a string with one exception - they MUST be enclosed in parentheses to be replaced.

Example:

Before String:

```
'a\n, b\n, c (a\n, b, c\n), d\n, e'
var1 := 'a
, b
, c (a
, b, c
), d
, e'
```

After string:

```
'a\n, b\n, c, (a b c), d\n, e'
var2 := 'a
, b
, c (a, b, c), d
, e'
```

I know there must be a clean regular expression pattern that can do this - but I can't get my head around it.

thanks very much...

Comment: it is simple for `Perl` language, but for oracle.. Hm.. Don't know, which kind of regular expressions it supported. `[\(](?:(.+)\n?)+[\)]` replace with $1 - this is match by `(.+)`

Comment: found this:
* REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, '((\)|^).*?(\(|$))|,', '\1') 
* from: [remove commas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826781/regexp-replace-remove-commas-from-string-only-if-enclosed-in-s) 
* But I can't make \n work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var2 := regexp_replace(var1, '((\)|^).*?(\(|$))|'||chr(10), '\1', 1, 0, 'n');
```

Comment: Egor, sort of relate, what would the regex look like if i want to replace it with something else instead of remove it.  Ex: 'a('||chr(10)||')b' --> 'a(NEWLINE)b' ?

Comment: @TANguyen - I don't know.  You can open new question for it.